# YAML - Serializing attributes which are types

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am having trouble YAML-serializing classes which have type references as members. I am using the safe loader of ruamel.yaml.

I ran all the following from a REPL prompt (to get multiple errors).

Initialization:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object

Y = YAML(typ="safe",pure=True)

# ==============

@yaml_object(Y)
class A(object):
    """Object I want to serialize"""
    yaml_tag = "!Aclass"
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
    def f(self):
        return self.type()
    pass

class T1(object):
    """This will be referenced."""
    pass

@yaml_object(Y)
class T2(object):
    """Another referenced object"""
    pass

class T3(object):
    """Yet another try"""
    pass
Y.register_class(T3.__class__)
```

Code that causes a failure:

```
Y.dump(A(T1), sys.stdout)
Y.dump(A(T2), sys.stdout)
Y.dump(A(T3), sys.stdout)
Y.dump(A(int), sys.stdout)
```

This outputs (only last lines of tracebacks):

```
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: <attribute '__dict__' of 'T1' objects>
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: <attribute '__dict__' of 'T2' objects>
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: <attribute '__dict__' of 'T3' objects>
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: <slot wrapper '__abs__' of 'int' objects>
```

*Any solution that lets me (safely) uniquely save the type (I need to generate objects of the type AND check whether an incoming object is of a certain type) would be appreciated.* A function or class that generates my required type would have the same problem of not being serializable, either.

---

P.S. I also possibly found a bug, where the parser will, for some reason, have different behavior depending on whether the same effective argument was (attempted) to be serialized.

```
Y.dump(A(str), sys.stdout)
Y.dump(A(str), sys.stdout)
Y.dump(A(str), sys.stdout)
Y.dump(A(str), sys.stdout)
```

Outputs:

```
>>> Y.dump(A(str), sys.stdout)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\main.py", line 352, in dump
    return self.dump_all([data], stream, _kw, transform=transform)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\main.py", line 383, in dump_all
    self.representer.represent(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 73, in represent
    node = self.represent_data(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 101, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\main.py", line 552, in t_y
    tag, data, cls, flow_style=representer.default_flow_style)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 371, in represent_yaml_object
    return self.represent_mapping(tag, state, flow_style=flow_style)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 206, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 101, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\main.py", line 492, in t_y
    tag, data, cls, flow_style=representer.default_flow_style)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 371, in represent_yaml_object
    return self.represent_mapping(tag, state, flow_style=flow_style)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 206, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 111, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[None](self, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\representer.py", line 375, in represent_undefined
    raise RepresenterError("cannot represent an object: %s" % data)
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: <slot wrapper '__add__' of 'str' objects>
>>> Y.dump(A(str), sys.stdout)
!Aclass
type: !type {}
>>> Y.dump(A(str), sys.stdout)
Traceback (most recent call last):
# same traceback here
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: <slot wrapper '__add__' of 'str' objects>
>>> Y.dump(A(str), sys.stdout)
!Aclass
type: !type {}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML expects to dump objects, and eventually does so by writing out scalar strings. `T1` is not an object (nor is `T2` or `T3`), and that is where the problem comes from. You can try to make each class reference into an object and uses tags on those, but that IMO merely complicates things.

Eventually it all boils down to getting a scalar representation, i.e. a string representation of the class into the file, so you might as well adapt `A()` to directly dump a string representation and read it back:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object
from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import DoubleQuotedScalarString


Y = YAML(typ="safe", pure=True)

# ==============

@yaml_object(Y)
class A(object):
    """Object I want to serialize"""
    yaml_tag = "!Aclass"
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type  #.__class__.__name__

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(
            cls.yaml_tag, u'{}'.format(node.type.__name__)
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        if '.' in node.value:  # in some other module
            m, n = node.value.rsplit('.', 1)
            return cls(getattr(sys.modules[m], n))
        else:
            return cls(globals()[node.value])


class T1(object):
    """This will be referenced."""
    pass


@yaml_object(Y)
class T2(object):
    """Another referenced object"""
    pass


class T3(object):
    """Yet another try"""
    pass
Y.register_class(T3)


for t in T1, T2, T3, DoubleQuotedScalarString:
    print('----------------------')
    x = StringIO()
    s = A(t)
    print('s', s.type)
    Y.dump(s, x)
    print(x.getvalue())

    d = Y.load(x.getvalue())
    print('d', d.type)
```

which gives:

```
----------------------
s <class '__main__.T1'>
!Aclass T1
...

d <class '__main__.T1'>
----------------------
s <class '__main__.T2'>
!Aclass T2
...

d <class '__main__.T2'>
----------------------
s <class '__main__.T3'>
!Aclass T3
...

d <class '__main__.T3'>
----------------------
s <class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString'>
!Aclass DoubleQuotedScalarString
...

d <class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString'>
```

If there are other attributes on `A()` that needs to be dumped/loaded, you should create a dictionary (with the string converted `.type`) and dump/load that.

I don't think you found a real bug, but that you experience a side effect from continuing after an error: the `Y` object (and its components) are left in an undefined state. You should not reuse a `YAML()` instance after catching errors. That should be more clear in the documentation. So if you want to do a `try/except` in the for loop , you should move the `Y = YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)` within the `try` part.

Comment: Alright, that seems to work fine, if I want to keep e.g. T2 in my . _However_, since I construct objects of the class given, and Y can't tell (at least, not from your A implementation) whether it's safe to load the object, I might be loading a malicious type in my code. In this case, T1 was "loaded" even though the class wasn't registered. One possible fix would be to check in A.from_yaml() whether the found class was registered by Y (i.e. is it in constructor.yaml_constructors?), I guess. Regarding the second part, that makes sense.

Comment: You are right about the safety, I thought about that while working on the answer, but forgot to include that. I would put all relevant types in a module (or mutiple modules in a subdirectory) and import them from there. Then you can check the string in the `node.value` in `A`'s `from_yaml()`. You can also make your own `@yaml_type` that sets a (unique) attribute on which you test (at dump and/or load time). There is no need for re-using ruamel.yaml's registering of objects to dump (which is essentially is something else).

Comment: I made a small mock-up in my answer, feel free to modify it (or your own answer) to make it safe. EDIT: I missed your comment while posting, not quite sure what you mean by it? Do you mean using a @yaml_type decorator to set a hidden attribute in an object? What prevents someone from doing the same thing to their own class and impersonating ours?

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto [Anthon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780809/5086686), I started modifying A.from_yaml to be safer, though I haven't went through all the cases for _check_registered(). The idea is to load all Types that Y would allow loading instances of, and prevent all other Types. Consider this a WIP:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object
from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import DoubleQuotedScalarString


Y = YAML(typ="safe", pure=True)

# ==============

@yaml_object(Y)
class A(object):
    """Object I want to serialize"""
    yaml_tag = "!Aclass"
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type  #.__class__.__name__

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(
            cls.yaml_tag, u'{}'.format(node.type.__name__)
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        if '.' in node.value:  # in some other module
            m, n = node.value.rsplit('.', 1)
            t = getattr(sys.modules[m], n)
        else:
            t = globals()[node.value]
        cls._check_registered(t,constructor, node)
        return cls(t)

    @classmethod
    def _check_registered(cls, t, constructor, node):
        # Check if type "t" is registered in "constr"
        # Note: only a very basic check, 
        # and ideally should be made more secure

        if hasattr(t,"yaml_tag"):
            if t.yaml_tag in constructor.yaml_constructors: 

                return
            raise Exception("Error: Tag not registered!")
        else:
            #
            raise Exception("Error: No attribute 'yaml_tag'!")
        pass

    pass

class T1(object):
    """This will be referenced."""
    yaml_tag = u"!T1"
    pass


@yaml_object(Y)
class T2(object):
    """Another referenced object"""
    yaml_tag = u"!T2"

    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing...")
        pass
    pass

class T2_bad(object):
    """Malicious class impersonating T2"""
    # Note: It's not registered
    yaml_tag = u"!T2"

    def __init__(self):
        print("Evil code here!")
        pass

    pass


class T3(object):
    """Yet another try"""
    yaml_tag = u"!T3"
    pass
Y.register_class(T3)



for t in T1, T2, T2_bad, T3, DoubleQuotedScalarString:
    try:
        print('----------------------')
        x = StringIO()
        s = A(t)
        print('s', s.type)
        Y.dump(s, x)
        print(x.getvalue())
        d = Y.load(x.getvalue())
        print('d', d.type)
        d.type()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
    pass
```

This returns:

```
----------------------
s <class '__main__.T1'>
!Aclass T1
...

Error: Tag not registered!
----------------------
s <class '__main__.T2'>
!Aclass T2
...

d <class '__main__.T2'>
Initializing...
<__main__.T2 object at 0x0000015B8EC82F60>
----------------------
s <class '__main__.T2_bad'>
!Aclass T2_bad
...

d <class '__main__.T2_bad'>
Evil code here!
<__main__.T2_bad object at 0x0000015B8EC82EF0>
----------------------
s <class '__main__.T3'>
!Aclass T3
...

d <class '__main__.T3'>
<__main__.T3 object at 0x0000015B8EC82E10>
----------------------
s <class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString'>
!Aclass DoubleQuotedScalarString
...

Error: No attribute 'yaml_tag'!
```

As can be seen, it's still not secure ("Evil code" was run), nor does it allow types without yaml_tag defined. Feel free to modify to fix this.